# shinyfiles not working if "includeHTML()" is there

Tags: r, shiny

very strange:

this works fine:

```
    ui <-mainPanel(
  shinyUI(bootstrapPage(shinyDirButton('STICK', "Data_directory", 
                                     "Choose the directory containing all your HCS data (works only while running the app via Rstudio on your computer):")
))
#,includeHTML("analysis/reports/multidim_anal_variable.html")
)

server <-  shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'STICK', roots=getVolumes(), restrictions=system.file(package='base'))
})

runApp(list(
  ui=ui,
  server=server
))
```

but if I uncomment the includeHTML line, it does not work anymore (when I click the button, no folder shows up in the window). (If it can't get an html to render, then it works.)

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, however there seem to be two issues: `mainPanel(...)` and `includeHTML(...)` both need to be within `shinyUI(...)`

Comment: sorry, there is no way for me to add the html file in the code itself...

I do not think it is linked to what you mention since there is no difference when playing around with or deleting  shinyUI(...)

Comment: used a workaround by using includeHTML and putting an empty files as default:
values$Outputshtml <- "reports/empty.html"
includeHTML1<- reactive({

    paste(readLines(values$Outputshtml), collapse="\n") 
})